# Remove Numbers and Symbols with Regex on CountVectorizer

Tags: regex, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

Currently, I have a CountVectorizer function

```
CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwords.words('spanish'),token_pattern=r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b')
```

with token_pattern by default used by Sklearn, and I have some results on get_features_names as follows:

```
000,02,10,100,1080,11,14,17,19,1994,1ª,2015,2017,22,24horas,2t0s6dgxnm,30,31,32,_aitor,_anamilan_,_cuteresa,_raquel97_
```

I would like to remove **numbers** and **_** symbol. I know that to do this i must to modify the regex function by default: `r'(?u)\b\w\w+\b'` so, Any suggestions?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

**Good words:** abrazo, aburrir, extrañar, además

**Bad words:** *anamilan*,000,02,10,100,1080

I would like to add ñ,á,é,í,ó,ú, I tried with `[á-ú_ñ]+` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like ?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern should match all the digits and _.

`[\d_]`

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add to the default patter to exclude digits and _ ?

Comment: Can you give some sample test strings and point out which ones should match and which ones should not.

Comment: Or just try this pattern - \b[a-zA-Z]{2,}\b

Comment: Thanks, I updated adding more information about what I want.